# Существует ли слово "подможет"?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, глаголы, разговорная-речь

Существует ли в разговорной речи слово "поДможет"?

Comment: От кого, где и по какому поводу услышано?

Answer (score 2):

В словаре **зафиксировано:**

**подмогать**, -аю, -аешь. *Несов. к* подмочь.
 **подмочь**, -могу, -можешь, -могут; *прош*. подмог, -ла, -ло; *сов. **Обл.*** То же, что помочь.

*[Мужик:]Батюшка, не тужи, надо будет, - мы **подможем**.*
(А.Н.Толстой, "Иван Грозный")

*Пойдём на пашню. Я вам **подмогу** немного.*
(Е.Мальцев, "От всего сердца")

Словарь русского языка в четырёх томах, том III, 1959.

Получается, что **"подможет"** существует и используется в значении **"поможет"**.
Не повсеместно, конечно, т.к. в словаре "обозначена" пометка: обл.(областное слово, выражение).

**Дополнение**, со ссылками:
[**Я вам подмогу немного**](http://litlife.club/br/?b=234299&p=57)
[**Мы подможем**](http://www.rulit.me/books/sobranie-sochinenij-v-desyati-tomah-tom-9-read-10166-110.html)

**Дополнение к дополнению**

ПОДМОГАТЬ - **подмочь** или *пск.* **подмогнуть** *кому*, помогать, пособлять, подсоблять, поспорить, **подавать** *помощь*.
Толковый словарь Даля. В.И. Даль. 1863-1866.
[**подмогать**](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/312298/%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%94%D0%9C%D0%9E%D0%93%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%AC)

**подмогать** (синонимы) - помогать, вывозить, подставлять плечо.
Словарь русских синонимов.

Современное использование подмогать = подмогнуть:
[**Васёк, подмогни!**](http://www.superdemotivator.ru/vasek-podmogni.html)
[**Улыбка бультерьера. 2017**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=oabMAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT14&lpg=PT14&dq=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B8&source=bl&ots=Wa-AQBYqOA&sig=AkGNv5wgz4aeCkV-BbDSK_ehNvU&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjt0_X6pNTTAhXjDpoKHdBqCkMQ6AEIXjAM#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B8&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

Словоформы: *подмогнуть, подмогнем, подможет* встречаются и в письменных источниках, но крайне редко (на два порядка реже, чем существительное *подмог(а/у/и)*).

Вот пример использования слова *подможет* в устной речи (в поговорке):

...Впрочем, лучше сказать попросту, «Чего чорт не сможет, так баба *подможет*…»... [Элиза Ожешко. Над Неманом (Вукол Лавров, 1896)]

Answer (score 0):

Да, существует. В словарях не зафиксировано, но используется (Яндекс выдает 3 тыс. результатов), и семантика достаточно прозрачна (помогите хотя бы частично). В общем, если от вас не требуют строго литературного языка, то использовать его можно, но я бы не рекомендовал, так как "поможете" имеет практически тоже самое значение, но звучит естественнее.

Comment: "так как "поможете" имеет практически тоже самое значение" - значение-то то же, а вот оттенок, которым могут быть окрашены слова в русском языке, характеризующий в какой-то степени говорящего, теряется. Например, иностранец осознанно (если не ошибется как иностранец) не скажет "подможем", тем более "подмогнем".

Answer (score 0):

Глагол Подмогать, -аю, -аешь от сущ. Подмога, ж. р.: (*На подмогу* прибежали ребята), т. е. на помощь, на выручку.

Answer (score 0):

Про словарь уже сказали. Впрочем, поскольку фиксации современной нет, можно считать, что несколько устаревает даже как разговорное.

По значению. Я полагаю, что значение глагольной приставки "под" (в отличие от "по") выражает этакую слабую, частичную или вторичную семантически форму глагола. Ехать - подъехать, держать - поддержать... То есть "подмочь" воспринимается как "немного, слегка помоги". При этом предположении подмоги-помоги воспринимаются как паронимы (похожие слова близкого, но не полные синонимы), а их противопоставления (оппозиция) выглядит вполне оправданной.

Comment: Я не никоим образом  не специалист по глагольным приставкам и по семантическим формам глаголов. Но, фиксация современная (1959; современная же!)  - есть, без пометок: устар., разг., -  которая означает, что глагол употребляется. Где? Как часто? В каких областях? - да, этого я в своём ответе привести не могу (да и словарь не акцентирует). Но ведь есть же!

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова *(1959; современная же!) - Ась?

Comment: _Morkovkin: поскольку **фиксации современной нет**..._  === Нет? См. http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%8C&all=x